# Error: OracleParameter object is already contained in a collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, wcf, ado.net

I have the below piece of code

```
var parametersList = new List<OracleParameter>();
if (items != null) {
       foreach (string item in items) {
           parametersList.Add(new OracleParameter(“@item”, item));
           ExecuteQuery(“sp_submitItem”, parametersList);
      }
    }
```

And in method `ExecuteQuery`, it loops through `parametersList` and adds them to `OracleParameterCollection` in `OracleCommand`, the using `OracleDataAdapter`, it fills the result in a `DataTable` and returns the result.

Why do you think I’m getting this error `OracleParameter object is already contained in a collection`

Comment: Because you can't have two parameters with the same name.  How id sp_submitItem defined?

Comment: @OldProgrammer what do you mean by I can’t have two params with the same name? Every time the loop loops, I pass one parameter to the stored procedure and it executes. and sp_submitItem takes one input parameter

Comment: you keep adding the same parameter to a list.

Comment: @OldProgrammer so I think the solution to this would be clear the parametersList after I call ExecuteQuery method, correct?

Comment: that should work

Comment: You can try the Clone() function.
`OracleParameter a = new OracleParameter(“@item”, item)
Parameters.Add(a.Clone());`